# multi-label segmentation in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, image-segmentation, multilabel-classification

I'm working on a segmentation task, where each pixel can belong to multiple classes - multi-label segmentation. The ground truth and the output (I get from U-Net) is `None x H x W x 3` in shape. Essentially, each pixel is represented by a vector of size 3. Am I doing the right thing if i call compile on the model like this:

```
model.compile(
    optimizer='rmsprop',
    loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

Or would I need to write a custom loss function for this task?

Thanks you!

Comment: If you are doing multi-label segmentation, yes, binary_crossentropy is what you need. So basically, it will apply binary crossentropy loss on each single label.

Comment: What framework did you use? Could you please share more info? We've been unable to do multi-label segmentation with many frameworks so far.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are performing a multi-label semantic segmentation, it would be a good idea to use some kind of weighted Binary Cross-Entropy. Usually in a multi-label semantic segmentation, there may be some labels that do not have enough training data and their performance may be masked by labels with high training information. This would in turn result in a higher overall accuracy but poor individual performance across all the labels.

Here is a good discussion on this issue. 
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6261